# Hide Menu After ScrollTop with JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple menu and when i click the "li" items the page automatically scrolls to that section. What I want to do is close my "dropMenu-nav" after scrolling finishes. I searched asked questions but I couldn't make it work. Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="dropMenu-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume" class="nav-link">RESUME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog" class="nav-link">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let scrollNav = $('.scroll');
  scrollNav.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body, html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    *$('.dropMenu-nav').animate({
      opacity: 0;
    }, 2000);*
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    let scrollBarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
    scrollLink.each(function(){
      let sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
      if (sectionOffset <= scrollBarLocation){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Scrolling part works perfectly but i cant find a way to hide my menu after scrolling. I don't see any error on my console also and I don't know where I am doing wrong to be honest. I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Can you explain how your dropdown menu is showing in the first instance? Then we can establish how to close it correctly.

Comment: I have a button and I use translateY(-100%) to translateY(0) and I toggle it to another class with js. I hope this i could answer you correctly. Here is my js code for first instance: 

const navToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-button');

navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('nav-is-open');
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to do the menu collapsing logic in the `complete` callback of `jQuery.animate`:

```
$('body, html').animate({
  scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  complete: function() {
    document.body.classList.remove('nav-is-open');
  }
});
```

Comment: Sadly, it's not working. I tried to make a simple example of that with codepen to explain myself a little bit better, i hope it helps and thanks for your time.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/uralkaraca/pen/gQxjQq)

Comment: Your `scrollNav` selector is wrong. It should be `$('.nav-link')`. And there is no menu toggling mechanism in the codepen, so toggling the body class `nav-is-open` to toggle the menu is still an assumption.

Comment: In the codepen (and probably in your project), the animate function is never called but the page successfully goes to the links targets thanks to the good old anchors.

Comment: After i changed it to $('.nav-link') it works and yes I was thinking how it worked with wrong selector so thanks to the good old anchors as you said :) Thank you for your help, i really appreciate.

Comment: Our pleasure to help :) Feel free to upvote and/or mark as accepted if you're satisfied with the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the menu **after** scroll then you will want to evaluate that code after the scroll completes. See the `complete` parameter in the [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) docs.

```
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
}, 1000, function () {
  $('body').removeClass('nav-is-open')
})
```

Comment: I tried both with jquery and js to remove 'nav-is-open' from body but it's not working. I made a snippet for explain it better, i really cant understand where the problem is. Thank you for your time and help.

Here is my link

Sadly, it's not working. I tried to make a simple example of that with codepen to explain myself a little bit better, i hope it helps and thanks for your time.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/uralkaraca/pen/gQxjQq)